# MySQL 1066: Not unique table/alias error even though I have defined table alias

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.1, mysql-error-1066

My Sql query is

```
Select a.sum_total FROM
OneWayNetTransactionRes a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
OneWayNetTransactionRes b
ON
a,frm_id = b.to_id
AND a.to_id = b.frm_id
```

Where `OneWayNetTransactionRes` is a view.

```
CREATE VIEW `OneWayNetTransactionRes` AS
SELECT frm_id, to_id, sum(amount) total_amount
FROM TransactionResolution
GROUP BY frm_id, to_id
```

Yet I get the error

```
1066: Not unique table/alias: 'b'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `.` instead of `,`:

```
ON a.frm_id = b.to_id
```

instead of

```
ON a,frm_id = b.to_id
```